# Variable area threshold for identifying objects - python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array which contains information of the size and location a series of shapes: where the array is zero, there are no shapes, where the array is not zero there is a shape. Different shapes are separated by  zeros - so that if you were to plot every point in the array, you would see a map of the various shapes. I hope that makes sense, if not here is an example array containing 4 different shapes:

```
np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
          [3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I need to count and identify these shapes but I only want to include the ones with an area above a certain threshold. 
I would like the area threshold to be 1/15 of the area of the largest shape in the field. (In the above example, the largest area would be 5.

The question is: How can I find (using python) the area of the maximum shape in the field without individually identifying each shape?

### Edit

To clarify what I mean by the 'shapes', the following code plots an image of the array, which shows 4 distinct objects:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
ind = np.nonzero(arr)
x = ind[0]
y = ind[1]
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you clarify where/how you get 4 shapes from the example data?

Comment: I've edited the post, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.label`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) to find the connected non-zero regions in your array, then use [`scipy.ndimage.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.sum.html) to find the area of each region:

```
from scipy import ndimage

labels, nshapes = ndimage.label(a)
areas = ndimage.sum(a, labels=labels, index=range(1, nshapes))

idx = np.argmax(areas)
biggest_shape = labels == (idx + 1)
```

In your example there happen to be two 'shapes' with the same area:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)

ax1.imshow(a, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax2.imshow(labels, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax3.imshow(biggest_shape, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

[image]

### Update

The `structure` argument passed to `scipy.ndimage.label` determines which neighbouring elements are considered to be 'connected' (see the docs linked above). If you want diagonally adjacent elements to be considered as connected, you can pass a 3x3 array of ones:

```
labels, nshapes = ndimage.label(a, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful. Is there a way I could adapt it to include the diagonals? I want the biggest shape to be the 'orange and yellow' shape combined with area 5.